# Inhibit all warnings option in Xcode project doesn't hide warning when building

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, cocoapods

1. Cocoapods inhibit_all_warnings! doesn't set the Pods project "Inhibit all warnings" to "Yes"
2. Xcode still displays pods warning after settings Pods project and individual pods "Inhibit all warnings" option to "Yes"

Cocoapods version: 0.39.0
Xcode version: 7.2

My pod is here:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'SnapKit', '~> 0.15.0'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'YLGIFImage'
pod 'Fabric'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'

# Changes build active architecture only
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1587

Comment: as Vizllx said, please check his link and try with `:inhibit_warnings => true` or `:inhibit_dependency_warnings => true`

Comment: I tried this too but the inihibit warning option in XCode is not changed whatever I try. I guess it's not working yet

Comment: If you are on Xcode 8 or greater there is a bug related to if the warning appears in a header file. More info: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6401

Answer (score 2):

Check for 'suppress warnings' in your build settings.

Comment: I want it to be automatic. basically through the podfile. Didn't try with the new version though. will try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

after you modify the podfile ,run pod install or pod update ,then build it again. just try.

Answer (score -1):

I never figured out how to make cocoapods' inhibit_all_warnings! work, but there is an option to hide warnings in Xcode's issue navigator.

1) Go to the issue navigator on the left panel (The `!` symbol in a triangle)

2) On the right side of the bottom searchbar click the `!` symbol in an octagon

Unfortunately it will hide warnings in your project, but at least you can focus on your errors.

Comment: Thank you. It is not exactly what I need, unfortunately. I'd like developers to be able to focus on the projects warnings by not being distracted by the Pods' warnings.